# How to extract and build list of dictionary items using jinja2 filter in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have sth like this:

Data:

```
---
modules:
 - name: m1
   migrations:
      - name: abc
        attr: testabc
      - name: def
        attr: testdef
 - name: m2
   migrations:
      - name: ghi
        attr: testabc
 - name: m3
   migrations: []
```

Ansible Task:

```
- name: All migrations
  set_fact:
   migrations: "{{modules|map(attribute='migrations')|list }}"
```

Output:

The output I see is sth like this:

```
[
  [
   {
     name: abc
     attr: testabc
   },
   {
     name: def
     attr: testdef
   }
 ],
 [
   {
    name: ghi
    attr: testabc
   }
 ],
 []
]
```

What I needed was:

```
[ 
   {
     name: abc
     attr: testabc
   },
   {
     name: def
     attr: testdef
   },     
   {
    name: ghi
    attr: testabc
   }     
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful to someone I manage to get a list of dict by:

```
- name: All migrations
  set_fact:
    migrations: "{% set migrations = migrations|default([]) + [item.1] %}{{migrations|list}}"
  with_subelements:
      - "{{ modules }}"
      - migrations
```

There might be a shorter version but I dont know that yet !